# performclick() causes crash in android java

Tags: android, button, crash, click, listener

I  need to trigger 30 button clicks on 30 buttons but app crashes probably due to memory over use, I used perform click for each of the buttons within a enter key listener.
Is there another way i can trigger a button click perhaps having one button that can trigger the 30 buttons at the same time which would mean needing only one performclick function.

Please help I have been stuck on this for over a year.

```
editext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if ("cat".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but1.performClick();
            }
            if ("dog".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but2.performClick();
            }
            if ("horse".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but3.performClick();
            }
            if ("pony".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but4.performClick();
            }
            if ("lion".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but5.performClick();
            }
            if ("monkey".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but6.performClick();
            }
            if ("goat".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but7.performClick();
            }
            if ("bear".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but8.performClick();
            }
            if ("mule".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but9.performClick();
            }
            if ("wolf".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but10.performClick();
            }
            if ("cow".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                but11.performClick();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

I will post logcat tomorrow.. Thanks for everyones help

Comment: post you code and error with logcat

Comment: show us where you initialize your buttons

Comment: but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                    public void onClick(View v) {  }};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare methods for actions and call their in onClickListeners.

Instead of:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             //something1
         });

btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             //something2
         });
```

You can write:

```
public void Something1(){
   //something1
}

public void Something2(){
   //something2
}
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              Something1();
         });

btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              Something2();
         });
```

If you will do it, no need to click button programmatically. You can only call those methods ( `Something1()`,  `Something2()` ).

Comment: Thanks can I use something like                editext.setOnKeyListener(new editext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {         
public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {             
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
 if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {                  

if ("cat".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {                    
    something1();                     
       }  });      then use ...public void Something1(){
   //something1
}